# I am getting date from sqlite using sqliteOpenHelper in Android and adding 70 days from that day

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview, sqliteopenhelper

I am getting date from sqlite using sqliteOpenHelper in Android and want to add days like 42, 70 etc 
Getting date is fine adding 42 from current date is fine but then I add 70 thats thats not working fine. 
Here is the code example
[image: Adding 42]

[image: Adding 70 and 98]

Comment: Posting code as images is frowned upon and will likely lead to downvotes. Saying it's not working without explaining how it's not working will lead to close votes as per *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*** I'd suggest you edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 70);
```